# Getting Error When Running Setup-Azure and Reset-Azure Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure

I am new to azure, I am reading from a book. I already downloaded azure modules but when I run the following cmdlets I got an error message saying that those are not defined cmdlets:

Setup-Azure
Reset-Azure

Anyone knows why?

Comment: This command is no more in newer version of azure powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this command in Azure Training book and stuffs provided by MS. In previous version of Azure powershell this was working.

Reset-Azure command was used to delete all resources except active directory in the subscription. To execute this command it asks for user credentials as it was responsible to delete resources.

I guess this command is no more present after azure powershell version 0.9.0. Latest is 2.2.0